# Statement : Every group of order 6 is cyclic - Proof that the statement is false

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Proof

Let G be a group of order 6. By Lagrange's Theorem, G has subgroups of order 1,2,3 and 6.

The subgroups of orders 2 and 3 have prime orders and are cyclic therefor. The subgroup contains an element g of order 2 and the subgroup contains an element h of order 3.

So therefore G is cyclic.
Is this correct or is there also proof of group G not being cyclic

Comment: Not true, try $D_3$ the dihedral group

Comment: "he subgroup contains an element g of order 2 and the subgroup contains an element h of order 3." but that doesn't mean the order of $hg$ is $6$ or that any element has an order of $6$.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, it is not correct.  Several mistakes here.

Lagrange does not say that such subgroups exist.  You are incorrectly applying a false converse.  Any subgroup of a group of order $6$ must have order $1, 2, 3$, or $6$.  This does **not** say that such subgroups must exist.

Also, a group $G$ of order $6$ having subgroups that are cyclic does NOT mean that the group $G$ itself is cyclic.  In fact, all groups have cyclic subgroups by definition (and usually plenty of them).

If you think the statement is false, then your job is to find a group of order $6$ that is not cyclic.  If you think it is true then you must prove that all such groups are cyclic.  How many groups of order $6$ do you know?

**Edit:** never mind, answer given away in the comments.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - I will try to continue as I was clearly wrongly stuck in my own Lagrange theorem

Comment: I guess with order 2 I can proof that group G itself is cyclic.

Comment: To see a small example to illustrate your mistakes more simply, notice that all proper subgroups of $G=\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ are cyclic, yet $G$ is not.  (Your mistakes are also common, so don't worry too much now.  You are right to try and fix them now.)

Comment: "I guess with order 2 I can proof that group G itself is cyclic. "  Which gets you nowhere.  The subgroup of order 2 is cyclic but that doesn't mean the group of which it is a subgroup is cyclic.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem does not say so, but since 2,3 are primes dividing 6, there must be elements of order 2 and 3 in the group, hence also subgroups of that order.